# Попарно заменить буквы в строке

Tags: python, словари

Есть задание из "TTAGCGCA", вывести "AATCGCGT" используя словарь ретрансляции. Как это сделать?

```
table = {
    "A": "T",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
    "G": "C"
}

print(list(table.keys()))
```

Comment: По проверкам, не закрывайте вопрос. Зачем вы это делаете?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) создаёт таблицу трансляции, [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate) её применяет:

```py
table = {
    "A": "T",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
    "G": "C"
}

trans = str.maketrans(table)
print("TTAGCGCA".translate(trans))
```

> ```
> $ python translate.py
> AATCGCGT
> ```

Comment: По-моему самый "правильный" вариант (не уничижая остальные). Поскольку данные методы built-in. И это сразу снимает несколько вопросов такие как: 1. Не изобретай велосипед: 2. Если есть метод встроенный в python, используй его

Answer (score 4):

Естественно неправильный, потому что вы выводите ключи, а не заменяйте символы на другие:

```py
def translate(target: str, dictionary: dict[str, str]) -> str:
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: dictionary.get(x, x), target))

table = {
    "A": "T",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
    "G": "C",
}

print(translate("TTAGCGCA", table))
```

UPD: Можно сделать так, как сказал @Stanislav Volodarskiy:

```py
def translate(target: str, dictionary: dict[str, str]) -> str:
    return ''.join(target.translate(str.maketrans(table)))
```

Comment: спасибо. это помогло

Comment: @Asterix Если ответ помог, его можно принять зелёной галочкой.

Comment: @MBo только она сначала не зеленая а серая :)

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант:

```py
table = {
    "A": "T",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
    "G": "C"
}

new_str = ''
for l in 'TTAGCGCA':
    new_str += table[l]
print(new_str)
```

Выводит:

```
AATCGCGT
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё короткий вариант:

```py
table = {
    "A": "T",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
    "G": "C"
}

print(*map(table.get, "TTAGCGCA"), sep='')
# AATCGCGT
```

Answer (score 2):

Словарь - это неспортивно, надо в нём рыться, искать ;)

```
s = 'ACGT'
rep = ''.join([chr(846807841//ord(c)%191) for c in s])
print(rep)
```

Comment: Это уже какой-то код-гольф получается)

Comment: Это просто приятно видеть (;

Comment: Сколько времени решение искалось? (`TTAGCGCA0123456789` -> `'AATCGCGTspº?j¥\x90»bj'`)

Comment: @anton Для двух пар - недолго, произвольный простой модуль взял и подбор делимого с проверкой четырех преобразований сгодился. Если больше пар понадобится, то надо уже алгебру использовать, видимо.